# Aligning components on two panels which are using flow layouts

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, flowlayout

I have two panels which are using flow layouts. These panels have same number of components (labels and text boxes). How do I align them?

Comment: you might consider using a third party LayoutManager (f.i. one of the big three MigLayout, FormLayout, DesignGridLayout) - personally, I think that none of the core managers fully fit real world usage: Spring- and GroupLayout designed for usage with visual builders and GridBagLayout overcomplex without being really powerful enough <ducking> :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layout managers don't communicate with one another that way. You can't use two separate FlowLayouts unless the components are all the same size.

You might be able to use a SpringLayout. Or more complex layouts would be the GridBagLayout and GroupLayout.

Check out the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples to decide which you would like to use.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make this to work only, when I have hardcoded some stuff, like sizes.

I would recommend to switch to a GridBagLayout instead at least.

Comment: WOuld getting the Hgap and VGap from Panel1's layout and Seting to Panel2's layout work?

Comment: No, because the gap is the same for every component. Its the preferred size of the component that matters.

Comment: with two panel and each FlowLayout isn't a best practice, believe me. GridLayout, GridBagLayout, Absolute Layout, FormLayout you will need. I have used SpringLayout too, but that component isn't free and is third party

Comment: SpringLayout is part of the JDK. There is no fee to use it.

Answer (score 0):

GridBagLayout is the layout you want to use if you need to align components and such. Read [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).